# jQuery - showing the added row

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

I have a web page that should insert new DB records and show them to the user.

What I want is that when I add a person, s(he) must see the added row.  I have the code below:

```
function AddData(par){

    var artistName =  $("input[name='"+par+"']").attr('id') + '-'+$("input[name='"+par+"']").val();

   $.post('/json/management/AddDataAjax2', 
    {
       "artistName": artistName
    },
    function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if(response =='ok'){
             alert("Başarıyla eklendi"); 
        }
         else{
             alert("Sanatçı bulunamadı, yönlendiriliyorsunuz");
             window.location.replace("http://www.sinemalar.com/management/artistAddEditRemove/");
         }
});
}
```

[image: example of showing added records]

The tabs are all divs.  I gave each tab an ID and added a div refresh after inserting the record. However, it renders original page that I loaded.  What's the solution, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a div where you want the data to be shown, something like this:

```
<div id="added"></div>
```

And then edit your jQuery to this:

```
function(response){
    console.log(response);
    if(response =='ok'){
         $("#added").append(artistName . "<br>");
         alert("Başarıyla eklendi");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead if refreshing the page, can you use append() to append the new item to your list?

edited: you might find this example useful:

test.html >>

```
 <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">                                                                                                      

 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("input[type='button']").click(function() {
        value = $("input[type='text']").val();
        $('ui').append("<li>"+value+"</li>");
     });
  });

</script>
<ui id='list'>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>

</ui> 

<input type='text'/><input type='button' value='Add'/>
```